# Friendly ID does not create new slugs on new inviations (devise-invitable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, friendly-id, devise-invitable

When I invite a user in my Rails 4 app using devise-invitable, a new friendly id is not created by the app.  I have the following code in my user.rb file

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  after_invite_path_for? || new_record? || name_changed? || slug.blank? || super
end
```

I've tried quite a few different options but can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are collecting your invitees name during the invitation acceptance process, this can be achieved by adding this to your controller:

**Application Controller**

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters    
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation).concat([:name, :slug])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ment you want to create the slug when creating an invite:

I've encountered the same problem.

the command i use to invite a user:
`User.invite!(email: "example@email.com", name: "John John")`

the problem is that for some reason the `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` is not called in this proccess.

my solution was to write a method to create the user slug

```
def slug_me!
  new_slug = [name.parameterize].join("-")
  if User.where(slug: new_slug).present? #check if the is a user with that slug already
    new_slug = [name.parameterize, User.last.id+1].join("-")
  end
  update_column(:slug, new_slug)
end
```

(in my app the new_slag will be unique. not sure about your app. you might need to change `[name.parameterize, User.last.id+1].join("-")` to something else that will fit your needs)

and override the `invite!` method that devise uses:

```
def invite!
  super
  slug_me! if should_generate_new_friendly_id?
end
```

(i've added `if should_generate_new_friendly_id?` so it wont create a slug if you invite the same person more then once)

in this case `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` will return `true` because `slug` is `nil` so `slug.blank?` will return `true`

its might not be the best solution, but it works for me.
(and im still looking for a better solution)

Comment: FriendlyId has a private method `set_slug`--better to use that imo than reimplementing all the logic. You can call it with `user.send(:set_slug)` or just `send(:set_slug)` if you're inside the model. 

Note this doesn't save the record--I'm calling `user.save(validate: false)` after `set_slug` to save, but your use case may be different. And as with using any private method, make sure you have a test covering this so you'll catch it if FriendlyId changes their implementation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on:

```
User.invite!(email: "example@email.com", name: "John John")
```

My solution was:

```
before_invitation_created :generate_slug

private

  def generate_slug
    return unless slug.nil?

    self.slug = set_slug
  end
```